# differentiation and integration 'tricks'

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, physics

$\frac{dL}{dt}=N$.

In a working on electrodynamics:

It says this implies $\int_{0}^{T}\frac{dL}{dt}dt=\int_{0}^{L}dL
=L=\int_{0}^{T}dN$

I've been staring at the last equality for an hour in an attempt to understand how that came about but to no avail.
[image]
Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Is $N$ a constant, or dependent on $t$?

Comment: N is the torque. Will edit

Comment: This is more or less the fundamental theorem of calculus in action. That is since we have that $\int_0^T I dt = Q = \int_0^Q dQ$ where the second integral is basically superfluous, then replace I with its definition in terms of the derivative of Q and you have this "identity"

Comment: @Triatticus It is unclear what you are trying to get across.